# Implementing asset download for mobile app with updates

Tags: java, tcp, udp

I want to implement a file server for a mobile app. This app requires so many tiny files to be downloaded from the server before it begins it's work And with updates from version to version some files are overwritten and some files gets modified or deleted.

Tried solutions:

1. Archive chunk download for each version, this means I create a zip file for each version and we serve the chunked zip file. The problem with this is that it's inefficient because extracting in the client requires too much extra space and second problem is that it's hard handling updates (downloading only necessary files when there are already some files on the client)
2. TCP download without archive, this one is inefficient because of too much overhead on TCP handshake for each file it wastes too much time
3. UDP download without archive, this one is not safe and we cannot guarantee the files downloaded on the client is healthy. Also doing checksum for each file on the client side is an expensive process we don't want to get into that.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

**Maybe it's woth mentioning that I use java spring boot on the server side**